# When to use httptest.Server and httptest.ResponseRecorder

Tags: unit-testing, go, tdd, httpserver

As title, when to use httptest.Server and httptest.ResponseRecorder?

It seems to me that I can also test my handlers to return correct response using httptest.Server. I can simply start a httptest.Server given with my implementation of handlers, then do validations on the response's body.

Please correct if I'm wrong, I am learning Go + TDD

Comment: The [package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/) has examples for both. Please clarify, what do you mean when you say "practical" and how these examples are not practical enough.

Comment: I probably shouldn't use the word 'practical', the thing is, I do not understand which to use under different condition. I shall update my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you just want to check, if your `http.Handler` does what it should, you don't need to use `httptest.Server`. Just call your handler with an `httptest.ResponseRecorder` instance and check the output as in the [example](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_ResponseRecorder).

The possible uses of `httptest.Server` are numerous, so here are just a couple that come to my mind:

- If your code depends on some external services and APIs, you can use a test server to emulate them. (Although I personally would isolate all code dealing with external data sources and then use them through interfaces, so that I could easily create fake objects for my tests.)
- If you work on a client-server application, you can use a test server to emulate the server-side when testing the client-side.

Comment: am i safe to assume that if i were to build a web app, i will not need httptest.Server at all?

Comment: I'd say yes. You generally don't need a server to unit-test your handlers.

Comment: Totally clear my doubts! Thanks! In my own understanding, `httptest.Server` is probably used as a mock for 3rd party API, just as what you mentioned. `httptest.ResponseRecorder` is what I'm looking for for TDD